# OrderBy DESC in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to order alphabetically Client list which I get from my LINQ query:

```
  var routeList = db.Clients
            .Where(p => p.ClientName
                .StartsWith(term))
                .Select(p => new { id = p.ClientID, clientName = p.ClientName })
                .OrderBy(p=>p.clientName).ToList();
```

But when I call it, it doesn't sorted alphabetically. Do you know why? Tnx.

update: So, excuse me of being not detailed on this..
I am using autocomplete function. So here is the code.
Controller:

```
 public JsonResult Search(string term)
    {
        //term = Request.QueryString["term"];
        var routeList = db.Clients
            .Where(p => p.ClientName
                .StartsWith(term))
                .Select(p => new { id = p.ClientID, clientName = p.ClientName })
                .OrderBy(p=>p.clientName).ToList();

        return Json(routeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And my view is:

```
@model IEnumerable<DataAccess.AdeccoView>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "SAR";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<p>
<input type="text" id="clientList" class="form-control"/>
</p>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clientList").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/AdeccoViews/Search",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return { label: item.clientName};
                    }));
                    }
            });
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I don't believe you :)  Please post a short but complete program that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you give us an idea about the output and how it is not sorted?

Comment: please view my updated post.

Comment: Ok, It works. I needed just to rebuild solution. :) Thanks guys!

Comment: your query is giving right output...problem is somewhere else... what output are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

When you call the `Select()` on your query, you change what the Queryable will return. Try to use `OrderBy` before the `Select()` and as a good pratice, try to keep the `Select()` as the last method of your queries. For sample:

```
var routeList = db.Clients
                .Where(p => p.ClientName.StartsWith(term))
                .OrderBy(p => p.ClientName)
                .Select(p => new { id = p.ClientID, clientName = p.ClientName })
                .ToList();
```